# Getting STDOUT, STDERR, and response code from external *nix command in perl

Tags: perl, stdout, stderr

I want to execute an external command from within my Perl script, putting the output of both stdout and stderr into a `$variable` of my choice, and to get the command's exit code into the `$?` variable.

I went through solutions in [perlfaq8](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#Why-can%27t-I-get-the-output-of-a-command-with-system%28%29?) and their forums, but they're not working for me. The strange thing is that I *don't* get the output of sdterr in any case, as long as the exit code is correct.

I'm using Perl version 5.8.8, on Red Hat Linux 5.

Here's an example of what I'm trying:

```
my $cmd="less";
my $out=`$cmd 2>&1`;
```

or

```
my $out=qx($cmd 2>&1);
```

or

```
open(PIPE, "$cmd 2>&1|");
```

When the command runs successfully, I can capture stdout.

I don't want to use additional capture modules. How can I capture the full results of the external command?

Comment: Just use [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/module/IPC::Run) which makes this easy.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3263912/2157640

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, the proper way to write this is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$cmd = 'lsss';  
my $out=qx($cmd 2>&1);
my $r_c=$?;
print "output was $out\n";
print "return code = ", $r_c, "\n";
```

You will get a '0' if no error and '-1' if error.

Answer (score 13):

This was exactly the challenge that David Golden faced when he wrote [`Capture::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/module/Capture::Tiny). I think it will help you do exactly what you need.

Basic example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Capture::Tiny 'capture';

my ($stdout, $stderr, $return) = capture {
  system( 'echo Hello' );
};

print "STDOUT: $stdout\n";
print "STDERR: $stderr\n";
print "Return: $return\n";
```

After rereading you might actually want `capture_merged` to join STDOUT and STDERR into one variable, but the example I gave is nice and general, so I will leave it.

Answer (score 5):

`STDERR` is intended to be used for errors or messages that might need to be separated from the `STDOUT` output stream.  Hence, I would not expect any `STDERR` from the output of a command like `less`.

If you want both (or either) stream and the return code, you could do:

```
my $out=qx($cmd 2>&1);
my $r_c=$?
print "output was $out\n";
print "return code = ", $r_c == -1 ? $r_c : $r_c>>8, "\n";
```

If the command isn't executable (perhaps because you meant to use `less` but wrote `lsss` instead), the return code will be -1.  Otherwise, the correct exit value is the high 8-bits.  See [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html).

Answer (score 2):

A frequently given answer to this question is to use a command line containing shell type redirection. However, suppose you want to avoid that, and use open() with a command and argument list, so you have to worry less about how a shell might interpret the input (which might be partly made up of user-supplied values). Then without resorting to packages such as IPC::Open3, the following will read both stdout and stderr:

```
my ($child_pid, $child_rc);

unless ($child_pid = open(OUTPUT, '-|')) {
  open(STDERR, ">&STDOUT");
  exec('program', 'with', 'arguments');
  die "ERROR: Could not execute program: $!";
}
waitpid($child_pid, 0);
$child_rc = $? >> 8;

while (<OUTPUT>) {
  # Do something with it
}
close(OUTPUT);
```

Comment: this is the best answer in this thread. with more code, it will prevent using shell redirection, it is usually bash. This example will be better if you detaily comment it. but it is detaily described in perldoc open function.

Comment: There is important question, why you first wait for child process and check RC, and after that you read its output? I thik it should be swapped. I think it is only one reason it works properly, it is pipe buffering made by the operating system. I think it will hang if external 'program' will produce big stream on stdout or stderr because stream redirection.