# How to check syntax of a perl script inside another one not using perl -c?

Tags: perl, compiler-errors

I have 2 perl scripts A and B. inside B.pl I want to check if there are syntax errors in A.pl

I'm using `` $result =`perl -c A.pl`; `` but I can't get the output in `$result`.
I need a perl command to do that. can you help?

Comment: For capturing output of an external command, see the [`qx`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) operator in [`perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html). For more advanced captures see also [Getting STDOUT, STDERR, and response code from external *nix command in perl](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8733131/2173773).

Comment: This is a textbook case of where SO fails lamely. *I* see a banner on top of this question that it already has answers. 2 actually. And as a result it is now closed. But both allegded answers are about how to capture stdout/stderr of a Perl ```system()``` command. Of course this question asks something completely different and yet 6 years later not even those SOers who so eagerly hijack and  edit questions, picking, at best, minor spelling mistakes and syntactical faux-pas, have not corrected it. Perhaps they have not noticed it even. The hallmarks of a Bureaucracy.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the output and check for the string `syntax OK`

**A.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

main();
exit 0;

sub main {
    my ($stuff) = @_;
    # Syntax Error
    print $stufff;

    # Runtime Error
    pint $stuff;

    # Runtime Error
    print $stuff->foo();
}
```

**B.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Test::More;

for my $file ( qw( A.pl B.pl ) ) {
    # 2>&1 means redirect STDERR to STDOUT so we can capture it
    chomp(my ($result) = qx( /usr/bin/env perl -cw $file 2>&1 ));
    ok( $result =~ m|syntax OK|m, "$file compiles OK" )
        or diag( "$file failed to compile : $result" );
}

done_testing();
```

**Output**

```
perl B.pl
not ok 1 - A.pl compiles OK
#   Failed test 'A.pl compiles OK'
#   at B.pl line 8.
# A.pl failed to compile : Global symbol "$stufff" requires explicit package name at A.pl line 12.
ok 2 - B.pl compiles OK
1..2
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 2.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
my $res = system("perl -c test.pl");
unless ($res) {
    print "OK\n";
} else {
    print "Syntax error!\n";
}
```

Comment: Author said that it doesn't work. And backtics captures STDOUT, not STDERR perl reports errors. Would be nice to check your code before posting it.